# Difference between docker and a setup installer

Tags: docker

I am quite new to docker and first thing I need to know is that how is it different from a setup installer. Docker, as it does, packages up everything (dependencies) and creates a single executable image (executable only by docker itself). Now a setup installer, installs the program into the system, creates directory, puts entries in the system registery, sets up everything for the program execution. If any dependency required, say any visual c++ redistributable package, update directx or may be update .net framework, the setup for that too is supplied with the program setup itself. So how a docker image is different from a setup file?

Comment: Docker is a container runtime. It used in development and partially in production. Just like a mechanic is needed to construct and maintain a car. I would not expect anyone of the end users to install docker in order to run our application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Setup Installer

- Puts requirement all over the place on your host machine.
- You cannot pick up an installed package on your machine and copy it to another machine.
- If you want to reuse an installation, you need to re-install it on another machine.
- Installation are OS-specific

### Docker Image

- Everything is in one file, a Docker Image. That file contains all dependencies for this one task (Mongo Database, Python programming, etc)
- The Image can be picked up and moved to another location, even another OS
- There are many many standard Images made for you and placed on Docker Hub
- Never worry about dependencies again
- An installation of a certain package can be removed simply by deleting the image. You don't have any carbage left in dark places on your system disk.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Docker, as I have read, is mainly associated with the development and testing phase of software development. But can it be used for actual software delivery purposes?

Comment: @Sank Yes, and no. Container orchestration (such as kubernetes) allows for containers to be deployed and managed at scale; most software vendors offer Helm Charts/Kubernetes Operators for delivering their software. However, Kubernetes itself still requires "traditional" software distribution models

Comment: Yes, Docker itself (without Kubernetes) can be used for software delivery. We run our applications on a number of Docker Containers on Digital Ocean platform. If the need arises to scale up, we will add Kubernetes functionality, but for now the application consists of 7 Docker Containers all working together.

Answer (score -1):

Manage chaos of run environment and code in subject. It is not for end user and less efficient as native app if product launch. It may avoid potential resources conflict. But may introduce another trouble too.